# Curl producing JSON error saving JS file in Terraform data

Tags: curl, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a test.js file that I am trying to pull in my Terraform folder like:

```
data external "file"{
    program = ["curl", "-o", "Content-Type:application/js", "${path.pwd}/testing.js", "https://raw.github.com/test/test.js"]
}
```

Keep getting command "curl" produced invalid JSON: unexpected end of JSON input. 
When I try to curl locally on my PC it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `external` data source is a last resort for when there isn't some other data source that can meet your needs in Terraform.

In this case it seems like you want to obtain JSON data from a remote HTTP endpoint. If so, it'll be less complicated to use [the `http` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/http/data_source.html):

```
data "http" "example" {
  url = "https://raw.github.com/test/test.js"
}
```

You can then use `data.http.example.response_body` to work with the data returned from that URL.

The URL you mentioned doesn't actually work, so I assume you have some other URL you intend to use in practice. If the URL in question returns JavaScript then you'll presumably just be working with it as a plain string, because Terraform has no built-in functionality for parsing or otherwise processing JavaScript code.

If the real URL you are trying to access actually returns *JSON* rather than JavaScript, then you can access the data structure represented by that JSON by using [the `jsondecode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsondecode.html). For example, you might assign the result to a [named local value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) so you can use it from multiple locations elsewhere in the module:

```
locals {
  example_data = jsondecode(data.http.example.response_body)
}
```

Elsewhere in your module, `local.example_data` will then refer to the value that resulted from decoding the JSON data, assuming that the body did indeed contain valid JSON. If it does not, then you'll see a similar error than you saw with the `external` data source: the `jsondecode` function can only decode valid JSON data.

Comment: It is javascript that I am trying to port. Namely some lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that curl is failing, it's that you aren't producing an output that terraform can consume. You must produce a json blob. Here's an external script that I use:

```
data "external" "terraform_versions" {
  program = ["scripts/terraform_versions.sh"]
}
```

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

jq -n --arg branch "${BRANCH}" --arg commit "${COMMIT}" '{"branch":$branch, "commit":$commit}'
```

Which outputs data as:

```
{
  "branch": "master",
  "commit": "abc123deadbeef..."
}
```

Which terraform CAN consume:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "terraform_branch" {
  name = "/${terraform.workspace}/tf/branch"
  type = "SecureString"
  value = data.external.terraform_versions.result["branch"]
  overwrite = true
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "terraform_commit" {
  name = "/${terraform.workspace}/tf/commit"
  type = "SecureString"
  value = data.external.terraform_versions.result["commit"]
  overwrite = true
}
```

More [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html)

EDIT: I've personally never used it, but there IS an http provider that might fit your need better. See [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/http/data_source.html)